# Knight's tour- backtracking (unable to solve for odd board sizes)

Tags: python, backtracking, recursive-backtracking, knights-tour

Below is the code I am using to test backtracking algo to solve knight's tour, and it's not able to solve for odd board sizes. I would really appreciate if someone could point out the error in the code.

The code works fine for boards of even size, but it fails to find a solution for boards of odd sizes.

```
def get_valid_moves_warnsdorff(moves, x, y, size):
    valid_moves = [(valid_move, len(get_valid_moves(moves, x + valid_move[0], y + valid_move[1], size))) for valid_move in get_valid_moves(moves, x, y, size)]
    sorted_moves = sorted(valid_moves, key=lambda w: w[1], reverse=False)
    return [move[0] for move in sorted_moves]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code requires that your tour is closed (that is, is must be possible to move from the last square back to the first square).

Such a tour does not always exist for all board sizes. In particular, for an `M x N` board, if both `M` and `N` are odd, there will be no closed tour.

To relax the requirements of your code so that open tours are accepted, just get rid of these lines:

```
origin_touchers = get_valid_moves(moves, 0, 0, size)
if (x, y) not in origin_touchers and -1 not in [grid[origin_toucher[0]][origin_toucher[1]] for origin_toucher in origin_touchers]:
    return False
```

If you do want to keep the closed tour requirement, you could simplify that long condition to `if not origin_touchers:`. There's no need to check `x,y` (since if you're on the last move you'd already have returned `True`) nor for `-1` on the grid (since `get_valid_moves` already ensures that all the coordinates it returns have `-1` on the grid).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I don't understand the code that well or python for that matter and this saved the day! :) Do you have a discord or something? I need a mentor of sorts would mean the world to me :) my twitter is @igococo.